# How can I make all of the background move as opposed to just one platform?

Tags: python, pygame, collision-detection

When I collide into a platform, the player is supposed to stop moving, and it did, but it also glitched slightly into the rectangle, so I found a work-around which is supposed to make the background move slightly over in order to compensate, but it only moves one platform, and if you were to repeatedly run into a platform it would cause it to shift indefinitely. I'm also currently just making it equal to the players left and right sides, but when I use `Level(self).bgX += 10`
inside the if statement in the player class that controls collisions it doesn't work, and I end up just glitching inside of it.

Here is my code:

```
import pygame

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
BLUE = (0, 255, 255)

SCREEN_WIDTH = 800
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 600

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self):


        super().__init__()


        width = 40
        height = 60
        self.image = pygame.Surface([width, height])
        self.image.fill(RED)


        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()


        self.xVel = 0
        self.yVel = 0


        self.level = None

    def update(self):
        self.calc_grav()


        Level(self).bgX += self.xVel



        block_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.level.platform_list, False)
    for block in block_hit_list:
        if self.xVel < 0:
            block.rect.left = 350 + 40
            self.friction()
        elif self.xVel > 0:
            block.rect.right = 350
            self.friction()

        self.rect.y += self.yVel


        block_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.level.platform_list, False)
        for block in block_hit_list:


            if self.yVel > 0:
                self.rect.bottom = block.rect.top
            elif self.yVel < 0:
                self.rect.top = block.rect.bottom


            self.yVel = 0

            if isinstance(block, MovingPlatform):
                Level(self).bgX += block.xVel

    def calc_grav(self):
        if self.yVel == 0:
            self.yVel = 1
        else:
            self.yVel +=0.5


        if self.rect.y >= SCREEN_HEIGHT - self.rect.height and self.yVel >= 0:
            self.yVel = 0
            self.rect.y = SCREEN_HEIGHT - self.rect.height

    def jump(self):
        self.rect.y += 2
        platform_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.level.platform_list, False)
        self.rect.y -= 2


        if len(platform_hit_list) > 0 or self.rect.bottom >= SCREEN_HEIGHT:
            self.yVel = -15

    def moveLeft(self):

        self.xVel = 6

    def moveRight(self):

        self.xVel = -6

    def friction(self):

        self.xVel = 0


class Platform(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, width, height):
        super().__init__()

        self.image = pygame.Surface([width, height])
        self.image.fill(GREEN)

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()


class MovingPlatform(Platform):

    xVel = 0
    yVel = 0

    boundary_top = 0
    boundary_bottom = 0
    boundary_left = 0
    boundary_right = 0

    player = None

    level = None

    def update(self):
        self.rect.x += self.xVel

        hit = pygame.sprite.collide_rect(self, self.player)
        if hit:



            if self.xVel < 0:
                self.player.rect.right = self.rect.left
            else:

                self.player.rect.left = self.rect.right

        self.rect.y += self.yVel


        hit = pygame.sprite.collide_rect(self, self.player)
        if hit:

            if self.yVel < 0:
                self.player.rect.bottom = self.rect.top
            else:
                self.player.rect.top = self.rect.bottom

        if self.rect.bottom > self.boundary_bottom or self.rect.top < self.boundary_top:
            self.yVel *= -1

        cur_pos = self.rect.x - self.level.bgX
        if cur_pos < self.boundary_left or cur_pos > self.boundary_right:
            self.xVel *= -1


class Level(object):

    def __init__(self, player):
        self.platform_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.enemy_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.player = player

        self.background = None


        self.bgX = 0
        self.level_limit = -1000

    def update(self):
        self.platform_list.update()
        self.enemy_list.update()

    def draw(self, screen):

        screen.fill(BLUE)


        self.platform_list.draw(screen)
        self.enemy_list.draw(screen)

        for platform in self.platform_list:
            platform.rect.x += self.player.xVel

        for enemy in self.enemy_list:
            enemy.rect.x += self.player.xVel

class Level_01(Level):

    def __init__(self, player):


        Level.__init__(self, player)

        self.level_limit = -1500


        level = [[210, 70, 500, 500],
                 [210, 70, 800, 400],
                 [210, 70, 1000, 500],
                 [210, 70, 1120, 280],
                 ]


        for platform in level:
            block = Platform(platform[0], platform[1])
            block.rect.x = platform[2]
            block.rect.y = platform[3]
            block.player = self.player
            self.platform_list.add(block)


        block = MovingPlatform(70, 40)
        block.rect.x = 1350
        block.rect.y = 280
        block.boundary_left = 1350
        block.boundary_right = 1600
        block.xVel = 1
        block.player = self.player
        block.level = self
        self.platform_list.add(block)


class Level_02(Level):

    def __init__(self, player):

        Level.__init__(self, player)

        self.level_limit = -1000


        level = [[210, 70, 500, 550],
                 [210, 70, 800, 400],
                 [210, 70, 1000, 500],
                 [210, 70, 1120, 280],
                 ]


        for platform in level:
            block = Platform(platform[0], platform[1])
            block.rect.x = platform[2]
            block.rect.y = platform[3]
            block.player = self.player
            self.platform_list.add(block)

        block = MovingPlatform(70, 70)
        block.rect.x = 1500
        block.rect.y = 300
        block.boundary_top = 100
        block.boundary_bottom = 550
        block.yVel = -1
        block.player = self.player
        block.level = self
        self.platform_list.add(block)


def main():
    pygame.init()


    size = [SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT]
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

    pygame.display.set_caption("Platformer with moving platforms")

    player = Player()

    level_list = []
    level_list.append(Level_01(player))

    current_level_no = 0
    current_level = level_list[current_level_no]

    active_sprite_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
    player.level = current_level

    player.rect.x = 350
    player.rect.y = SCREEN_HEIGHT - player.rect.height
    active_sprite_list.add(player)


    done = False


    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    # -------- Main Program Loop -----------
    while not done:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                done = True

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    player.moveLeft()
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    player.moveRight()
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    player.jump()

            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT and player.xVel > 0:
                    player.friction()
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT and player.xVel < 0:
                    player.friction()

        active_sprite_list.update()

        current_level.update()



        current_position = current_level.bgX
        if current_position < current_level.level_limit:
            if current_level_no < len(level_list)-1:
                player.rect.x = 350
                current_level_no += 1
                current_level = level_list[current_level_no]
                player.level = current_level
            else:

                done = True


        current_level.draw(screen)
        active_sprite_list.draw(screen)


        clock.tick(60)


        pygame.display.flip()

    pygame.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Is there a way to make the entire background shift as opposed to just the platform? It would also help if someone could tell me why you can't just hold the right arrow key and jump simultaneously after you collide with a platform.

For Valentino:
Here is my code for moving a single block after it is touched:

```
block_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.level.platform_list, False)
    for block in block_hit_list:
        if self.xVel < 0:
            block.rect.left = 350 + 40
            self.friction()
        elif self.xVel > 0:
            block.rect.right = 350
            self.friction()
```

Comment: I'd say your workaround is the wrong approach. Try to fix the player position after the collision so that there is no glitch instead of moving the background. And try to post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Digging through all your code is a lot of work, it's difficult to find somebody which will do it.

Comment: Alright, I'll try

Comment: I tried, but that just makes my character permanently stuck inside of the block, but this may be due to me misunderstanding your comment. After the collision, I make the player's x value equal to 350 again, which is where it usually is, but my collision system works by making the players x value equal to the blocks value after stopping, and since my character moves moderately fast it needs to compensate for the change, which is why it moves back. My new code for collisions can be seen at the bottom of my previous question

Comment: Sorry, now I see your point. Your character never moves along x axis, it's the background which is moved. If you want to stay stick to this approach, then yes, you need to move the whole background. Coud you point the part of the code where you adjust the coordinates of the platform after collision? You should be able to follow that approach for all the platforms, and not only the one which collides.

Comment: Alright. The code where I adjust the coordinates will appear at the bottom of the previous question.

Comment: It's been updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two lines in your collision check:

```
 block.rect.left = 350 + 40

 block.rect.right = 350
```

adjust the coordinates of the current block only. What you should do is adjust the coordinates of all blocks. Calculate the correct correction and then move all blocks of the given amount along x axis.
In your `update` method of `Player` do:

```
correction = 0
block_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.level.platform_list, False)
for block in block_hit_list:
    if self.xVel < 0:
        self.friction()
        correction = self.rect.right - block.rect.left
    elif self.xVel > 0:
        self.friction()
        correction = self.rect.left - block.rect.right

if correction != 0:
    for block in self.level.platform_list:
        block.rect.x += correction

self.rect.y += self.yVel
```